# Define keywords for spotlight search in Ionic app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, corespotlight

Is it possible to define keywords to an Ionic App, so it can be found in spotlight search inside iOS?

I mean you can search for "music" in an iPhone and Spotify app will show (even though it does not have music in its name).

Thanks in advance